# Senior Preferred vs Senior Unsecured Bonds

Tags: fixed-income, capital-structure

What's the difference between Senior Preferred bonds and Senior Unsecured bonds. I understand the difference Senior Preferred vs Senior Non-Preferred bonds. But Senior Preferred and Senior Secured are quite similar in terms of rating, spreads, etc, except that only banks issue Senior Preferred bonds.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer...

The EU amended Bank Recovery and Resolution Directive (BRRD).

Accordingly, Germany amended Section 46f of the German Banking Law effective July 21, 2018 to implement this.

Only banks can issue senior preferred bonds.

A write-up from BaFin, the German regulator: https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/Merkblatt/A/dl_Merkblatt_46f_KWG_nach_Konsultation_f_0205_en.pdf

A write-up from UniCredit: https://www.research.unicredit.eu/DocsKey/credit_docs_9999_163698.ashx?EXT=pdf&KEY=n03ZZLYZf5miJJA2_uTR8g-DI71YB98JAgbG318Wjo0=&T=1

An example is BPCS 24s, ISIN FR001400CUI6.

There are some subtle differences in subordination if the bank fails,unlikely to affect ratings or spreads much.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the only difference is that banks usually issue senior preferred notes. However, certain Banks in certain regions (Canada for example) only issue senior unsecured notes which are bail-in capital in a credit event and so trade more similar to senior non-preferred notes.

Senior secured notes are very different to senior preferred in that the holder of the notes have dual recourse to both the issuer and the assets they are secured by.